# Mountaineering trousers with short legs

Tags: mountaineering, waterproof-clothing, alpine

Do any mountaineering / Alpine style waterproof trousers come in short legs? I have a 29" inside leg and I've really struggled to find anything to fit.

Comment: What would be the use case for waterproof short trousers?

Comment: While I have seen regular/short/long inseam pants over the years, any answer to this kind of question risks being outdated really quickly at the pace products appear, disappear, or are updated. I'd advise just doing a Google search with "short inseam waterproof pants" terms. The first result in my search has 30" inseam.

Comment: This may be too obvious, but do you know someone who sews well?

Comment: I suspect the OP is looking for long pants, but with an inseam appropriate for a person of shorter stature. I have a 28" inseam and finding pants for outdoor activities that aren't ridiculously long is tough, and seems to have been getting tougher in the last few years. I paid $100 for a pair of softshell pants, and then paid $50 to have them taken up a few inches.  I tried to do the same with some full zip Gore-tex rain pants, but because of the zippers in the legs the alteration was going to cost $150! Mass production is cheap, custom tailoring is expensive!

Comment: VTC since models come and go every year. SE answers should remain valid over time.

Comment: @Guran Vote to leave open, as there is an answer that is valid over time.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Glad to be wrong, I retract my vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look in the women's section of your favorite clothing supplier.

The average woman is shorter than the average man, which means there are often smaller sizes in these selections.  They also have some options that are not available in mens clothes.

Unfortunately Women's clothes often have small pockets, so when shopping the women's section, besure to test the pockets before purchasing.

Not ashamed to say, some of my outdoor clothes come from the women's section.

Comment: James, I was going to say this! Also, depending on the rest of the body size, the younger men section can also help. I'm a women, but due to various measurement needs, that's the department I use for pants. I also have an odd-numbered inseam length, and many regular men and women's clothing only come in even numbers.

Comment: Sewing isn't really an option for Alpine waterproof trousers. Full length taped zips and internal gaiters make for very complicated alterations. The womens section may well work.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes they are normal pants, without a zipper on the leg.

Put them on, then roll up the cuffs to the length you want.  Normally pants that are worn with boots are 1-2" longer to keep the bottom over your boot top even with a sharply bent knee.

Safety pin them in place.

Remove.

Go to your local dry-cleaner and ask if they do alterations.  Usually changing the length of pants is just a few dollars.